# Kotlin - What does @Stable do?

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations

I've been following [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/jetpack-compose-auto-complete-search-bar-853023856f0f) and I'm unsure what the @Stable annotation does. I have seen [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/Stable) but I need an example to better understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@Stable` is an Annotation that will tell the compiler that it's value will not change and return exactly the same value. This should only be applied to functions or values that are static the whole time.

The main reason why this is used is simple:

1. **Increased performance** -> compiler will be faster because you tell him how to handle it.
2. You can **return** always the **same value**, that can't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Stable` annotation indicates that a value will always notify Composition (aka trigger a new recomposition) **if it ever changes**.

Anything immutable, including primitives, are therefore "stable" because **they never change** - meaning they don't have to care about notifying Composition at all.

For example, this data class can be marked as stable as it is immutable.

```
@Stable
data class Movie(val id: Int, val name: String)
```

This means that a composable that takes movie as an input can be skipped. For example, in the composable below, `MovieOverview` can be skipped when `liked` changes. This allows for increased performance because less work needs to be done.

```
@Composable
fun MovieCard(movie: Movie) {
    val liked = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Column {
        MovieOverview(movie)
        Checkbox(
            checked = liked.value,
            onCheckedChange = { isChecked -> liked.value = isChecked }
        )
    }
}
```

}

But, this also means that mutable items can be stable, as long as they notify Composition on change. `MutableState` is the best example of this. It is marked as stable, but is also mutable. And whenever you change the state value, recomposition will be triggered.

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/MutableState
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lifecycle#skipping